# How to cascade pop up windows (i.e. offset the X and Y position) in a Flex application?

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, popup, flash-builder

I have a simple Flex (Flash Builder) application which pops up a new window when a user clicks on a map.  The user can make subsequent clicks on the map to have additional pop up windows appear, each of which currently pop up on top of the initial/previous pop up window(s) (i.e. at the same X and Y position).  I want to modify the application in such a way that each new pop up window will be rendered slightly offset from the previous pop up window.  A coworker has suggested I try to find a way to leverage existing window cascading functionality in Flex, but so far I've not found anything which can manage this for you.  Is there such a solution cooked into Flex already, or should I roll my own by calculating the new pop up window's X and Y position based on the last pop up window's X and Y position?

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

--James

Answer (score 0):

In the popup function you can read the X and Y position of the pop-up the user clicked on and change the X and Y position of the new pop-up by adding 5 or 10px to each one.

Comment: If the question is how to do this, please add the code for the function you are using to create the popup.